# How to capture image from the recorded project with *.camrec format

Tags: camtasia

I have a Camtasia project named aaa.camrec and want to capture an image in the middle of the video. How can I do it with highest possible original recording resolution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move the time-slider to the frame you want to export,

Click "**File**" > "**Produce special**" > "**Export frame as...**" or press `CTRL + F`

Choose the name and location on where you want to save the file and click "**Save**".

[image: how to save a frame]

Answer (score 2):

@Mrtn answer is correct for Camtasia Studio 8.  In CS 9, you still scroll the playhead to the exact frame you desire.  Then go to **`"Share" > Export Frame As...`** or press **`CTRL + F`**

[image: camtasia 9 how to export frame]

The exported file will be `PNG` format, which you can then preview or edit in any photo editor program like SnagIt.

Answer (score 0):

In Camtasia 2020, there is a new icon that looks like a camera in the timeline tools. Next to the "Copy" and "Paste" icons, to the left of the timeline zoom slider.

[See Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aXG1.png)